# Swift 2 to swift 3 conversion Midi Input

Tags: xcode, swift, midi, swift-playground, swift3

I'm hoping someone may be able to help i'm using Xcode 8 and swift 3
I have a playground file Xcode 7 swift 2 that involves a Midi callback for Midi Input everything works fine in 7

I tried a conversion to 8 and it brought up errors regarding memory and a few name changes mostly of what i believe to be non serious i also redefined the infinite loop using PlaygroundSupport
However the error i cannot get over involves MyMIDIReadProc at

```
MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, "MidiTest_InPort", MyMIDIReadProc, nil, &inPort);
```

The error says
Cannot convert value of type '(pktList: UnsafePointer, readProcRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer, srcConnRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer) -> Void' to expected argument type 'MIDIReadProc' (aka '@convention(c) (UnsafePointer, Optional>, Optional>) -> ()')

My understanding is that it needs a @convention(c) wrapper of some description inserted. I think i'm on the right track because you can wrap a function but my knowledge of where to put it has run out. Again i was hoping some one might be able to advise

Thanks for reading
apologies for any bad language as i'm self taught

Here is the original Xcode 7 code

```
            import Cocoa
            import CoreMIDI
            import XCPlayground

            func getDisplayName(obj: MIDIObjectRef) -> String
            {
                var param: Unmanaged<CFString>?
                var name: String = "Error";

                let err: OSStatus = MIDIObjectGetStringProperty(obj, kMIDIPropertyDisplayName, &param)
                if err == OSStatus(noErr)
                {
                    name =  param!.takeRetainedValue() as String
                }

                return name;
            }

            func MyMIDIReadProc(pktList: UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>,
                readProcRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, srcConnRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void
            {
                let packetList:MIDIPacketList = pktList.memory;
                let srcRef:MIDIEndpointRef = UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIEndpointRef>(COpaquePointer(srcConnRefCon)).memory;
                print("MIDI Received From Source: \(getDisplayName(srcRef))");

                var packet:MIDIPacket = packetList.packet;
                for _ in 1...packetList.numPackets
                {
                    let bytes = Mirror(reflecting: packet.data).children;
                    var dumpStr = "";
                    // bytes mirror contains all the zero values in the ridiulous packet data tuple
                    // so use the packet length to iterate.
                    var i = packet.length;
                    for (_, attr) in bytes.enumerate()
                    {
                         dumpStr += String(format:"$%02X ", attr.value as! UInt8);
                        --i;
                        if (i <= 0)
                        {
                           break;
                        }
                    }

                    print(dumpStr)
                    packet = MIDIPacketNext(&packet).memory;
                }
            }

            var midiClient: MIDIClientRef = 0;
            var inPort:MIDIPortRef = 0;
            var src:MIDIEndpointRef = MIDIGetSource(0);

            MIDIClientCreate("MidiTestClient", nil, nil, &midiClient);
            MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, "MidiTest_InPort", MyMIDIReadProc, nil, &inPort);

            MIDIPortConnectSource(inPort, src, &src);

            // Keep playground running
            XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true;
```

And here is the Xcode 8 code converted

```
            var str = "Hello, playground"
            import Cocoa
            import CoreMIDI
            import XCPlayground
            import PlaygroundSupport


             func getDisplayName(obj: MIDIObjectRef) -> String
             {
             var param: Unmanaged<CFString>?
             var name: String = "Error";

             let err: OSStatus = MIDIObjectGetStringProperty(obj, kMIDIPropertyDisplayName, &param)
             if err == OSStatus(noErr)
             {
             name =  param!.takeRetainedValue() as String
             }

             return name;
             }


            func MyMIDIReadProc(pktList: UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>,
                                readProcRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, srcConnRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void
             {


             let packetList:MIDIPacketList = pktList.pointee;

             let srcRef:MIDIEndpointRef = UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIEndpointRef>(OpaquePointer(srcConnRefCon)).pointee;
             print("MIDI Received From Source: \(getDisplayName(obj: srcRef))");

             var packet:MIDIPacket = packetList.packet;
             for _ in 1...packetList.numPackets
             {
             let bytes = Mirror(reflecting: packet.data).children;
             var dumpStr = "";

             var i = packet.length;
             for (_, attr) in bytes.enumerated()
             {
             dumpStr += String(format:"$%02X ", attr.value as! UInt8);
             i -= 1;
             if (i <= 0)
             {
             break;
             }

             }

             print(dumpStr)
             packet = MIDIPacketNext(&packet).pointee;
             }
             }

            var midiClient: MIDIClientRef = 0;
             var inPort:MIDIPortRef = 0;
             var src:MIDIEndpointRef = MIDIGetSource(0);

             MIDIClientCreate("MidiTestClient", nil, nil, &midiClient);

             MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, "MidiTest_InPort", MyMIDIReadProc, nil, &inPort);

            MIDIPortConnectSource(inPort, src, &src);


             PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointer types are drastically changed in Swift 3. Many C-based APIs' signatures are changed accordingly.

Following those changes manually would be painful. You can make Swift work for you, with a little modification.

Try changing the function header:

```
func MyMIDIReadProc(pktList: UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>,
                                readProcRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, srcConnRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void
             {
```

to a closure declaration:

```
let MyMIDIReadProc: MIDIReadProc = {pktList, readProcRefCon, srcConnRefCon in
```

Swift infers argument types perfectly in this style.

You may need to fix pointer type conversion:

```
    let srcRef:MIDIEndpointRef = UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDIEndpointRef>(OpaquePointer(srcConnRefCon)).pointee;
```

to something like this:

```
    //I'm not sure using `!` is safe here...
    let srcRef: MIDIEndpointRef = UnsafeMutablePointer(srcConnRefCon!).pointee
```

(By the way, the equivalent part in your Xcode 7 code is a little bit redundant. You have no need to use intermediate `COpaquePointer` there.)

---

In Swift 3, pointers cannot be nil, and nullable pointers are represented with Optionals. You may need many other fixes to work with C-based APIs in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

OOPer is pointing (ahem) you in the right direction. Here is a blog post on using [Swift 3 Core MIDI](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-3-core-midi/) along with a working github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're working with CoreMIDI 1.3 or later, you may have more luck using [`MIDIInputPortCreateWithBlock`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremidi/1495333-midiinputportcreatewithblock) instead of `MIDIInputPortCreate`.

This method takes a Swift block as a parameter instead of requiring an `@convention(c)` function reference, making it more amenable to use within methods belonging to Swift classes, e.g.:

```
public func midiReadBlock(ptr: UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>, _: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void {
    let list: MIDIPacketList = ptr.pointee
    ...
}
```

You may also find these two extensions useful.

This one (derived from [here](https://gist.github.com/jverkoey/defb7f9f3578d5cb3ff3)) allows you to iterate directly over a `MIDIPacketList` using `for pkt in list`:

```
extension MIDIPacketList: Sequence {

    public func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<MIDIPacket> {
        var iterator: MIDIPacket?
        var nextIndex: UInt32 = 0

        return AnyIterator {
            nextIndex += 1
            if nextIndex > self.numPackets { return nil }
            if iterator != nil {
                iterator = withUnsafePointer(to: &iterator!) { MIDIPacketNext($0).pointee }
            } else {
                iterator = self.packet;
            }
            return iterator
        }
    }
}
```

and this one adds a method to a `MIDIPacket` to extract the contents as a `[UInt8]` instead of having to use the really broken tuple syntax:

```
extension MIDIPacket {
    public var asArray: [UInt8] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self.data)
        let length = Int(self.length)

        var result = [UInt8]()
        result.reserveCapacity(length)

        for (n, child) in mirror.children.enumerated() {
            if n == length {
                break
            }
            result.append(child.value as! UInt8)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```